# Extract archive with BSD tar to directory with same basename

Tags: tar, macos, bsd, gnu-tar

GNU tar allows to extract the contents of an archive to a directory named after the basename of the archive.

```
$ touch foobar
$ gnutar czf archive.tar.gz foobar
$ gnutar --one-top-level -xf archive.tar.gz
$ ls archive/foobar
archive/foobar
```

I can get the same result with BSD tar by running multiple commands.

```
$ destdir=$(basename archive.tar.gz .tar.gz)
$ mkdir $destdir
$ bsdtar -C $destdir -xf archive.tar.gz
$ ls archive/foobar
archive/foobar
```

I would however like to run a *single* command just as with GNU tar. One could of course wrap the commands into shell script or shell function but I'm wondering if there is some *builtin* of BSD tar that produces the same result thus requiring only a single command?

---

<sup>Background: I would like to use BSD tar because GNU tar currently does not seem to support extended attributes on non-Linux plattforms, at least GNU tar installed via Homebrew on macOS is currently not compiled with extended attributes support.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You've almost solved your own problem.  With some slight parameterization of your code, you could create a function and place it in your `.profile` or other `bash` start-up script.

```
guntar() {

destdir="$(basename "$1" .tar.gz)"
mkdir "$destdir"
bsdtar -C "$destdir" -xf "$1"
ls -l "$destdir"/

}

$ guntar archive.tar.gz 
total 1
-rw-------  1 jim  wheel  0 Jan 11 09:34 foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

With zsh:

```
() { bsdtar -"s|^|${${1:t}%.(tar*|t?z|xip|iso|7z)}/|' -xf $1; } path/to/some/file.tgz
```

Which passes the path of the file to an anonymous function inside which we use the `-s` option to prepend the basename stripped of the  suffix for some of the archive formats supported by bsdtar to the extracted paths.